# More succinct way to remove multiple elements from a list?

Tags: python, string, list, split, strip

I am trying to slice and strip a string. I have written the following code:

```
my_list = ['from ab1c_table in WXY\nprevious in time',
        'from abc3_table in MNO\nprevious in time',
        'from ab1_cow_table in DZMC1_IN tab\ncurrent in time',
        'from abc4_table in ERDU\ncurrent in time']
my_list_1 = []
for j in my_list:
  s = j.split(" ")
  s.remove('from')
  s.remove('in')
  s.remove('in')
  s.remove('time')

  for k in s:
    k = k.replace('current', '')
    k = k.replace('previous', '')
    k = k.replace('\n', '')
  my_list_1.append(k)
  if 'tab' in my_list_1:
    my_list_1.remove('tab')

print(my_list_1)
```

It is working fine but the issue is I have to remove each word separately. Is there a way to do it in fewer lines?
The output I am looking for is:

```
['WXY', 'MNO']
```

EDIT 1 -

How do I get this output -

```
['ab1c_table', 'WXY', 'abc3_table', 'MNO', 'ab1_cow_table', 'DZMC1_IN', 'abc4_table', 'ERDU']
```

Comment: You could create a list of words you need to remove, and iterate through that.

Comment: If the pattern is always "from x in y" it might be more reasonable to split every item at whitespace, then the target item would always be the 4th in the list.

Comment: I think you probably meant "split" a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you have in mind, but usually regular expressions are useful for extracting patterns from strings. For example:

```
import re
my_list = ['from ab1c_table in WXY\nprevious in time', 
           'from abc3_table in MNO\nprevious in time']

my_list1 = [re.findall(r" ([A-Z]{3})\n", s, )[0] for s in my_list]
print(my_list_1)
```

**Edit:**

Here is a modification of the regex pattern reflecting the additonal  string samples provided by OP in a comment below:

```
mylist = ['from ab1c_table in WXY\nprevious in time', 
          'from abc3_table in MNO\nprevious in time', 
          'from ab1_cow_table in DZMC1_IN tab\ncurrent in time', 
          'from abc4_table in ERDU\ncurrent in time']

my_list1 = [re.findall(r"_table in (\S+)(?:| tab)\n.* in time", s)[0] for s in mylist]

print(my_list1)
```

This gives:

```
['WXY', 'MNO', 'DZMC1_IN', 'ERDU']
```

**Edit 2:**

Version capturing `_table` patterns:

```
import re
from itertools import chain

mylist = ['from ab1c_table in WXY\nprevious in time', 
          'from abc3_table in MNO\nprevious in time', 
          'from ab1_cow_table in DZMC1_IN tab\ncurrent in time', 
          'from abc4_table in ERDU\ncurrent in time']

my_list1 = list(chain(*[re.findall(r"from (\S+_table) in (\S+).*?\n.* in time", s)[0] for s in mylist]))

print(my_list1)
```

It gives:

```
['ab1c_table', 'WXY', 'abc3_table', 'MNO', 'ab1_cow_table', 'DZMC1_IN', 'abc4_table', 'ERDU']
```

Comment: Thsi would be a problem for "from ABC1_table" or XYZ not being upper case ascii.

Comment: @tdelaney This depends on what the result is supposed to be  - sequences of three capital letters, three capital letters followed by newline? I am not certain.

Comment: I'm not sure either. We don't know enough about these strings to really say. Lets see if OP can clarify.

Comment: This may be bordering on an XY problem.

Comment: @sj95126 - plus one that.

Comment: @tdelaney the strings can be of form- `from ab1_cow_table in DZMC1_IN tab\ncurrent in time` or `from abc4_table in ERDU\ncurrent in time`

Comment: In the `from ab1_cow_table in DZMC1_IN tab` example, should the matched output be "DZMC1_IN tab" or just everything up until the space?

Comment: @tdelaney In the OP's original code 'tab' is getting removed, so I guess it should not be matched.

Comment: @bb1 yes, I don't need tab. This is working for this output, if I need a slightly different output how to get that? I have edited the question

Comment: @KatrinaMarrie I added a version that produces the new output.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from the question what is variable in the strings, but it seems like this regular expression would do. The goal is to match everything that is static with some wildcards and  parenthesized capture groups for the data you want in the result. Since you want two pieces of data in the order they are found in the string, you can create two capture groups and extend the result list.

```
import re
  
my_list = ['from ab1c_table in WXY\nprevious in time',
        'from abc3_table in MNO\nprevious in time',
        'from ab1_cow_table in DZMC1_IN tab\ncurrent in time',
        'from abc4_table in ERDU\ncurrent in time']

result = []
for value in my_list:
    result.extend(re.match(r"from (.+_table) in (\S+)", value).groups())
print(result)
```

Result

```
['ab1c_table', 'WXY', 'abc3_table', 'MNO', 'ab1_cow_table', 'DZMC1_IN', 'abc4_table', 'ERDU']
```

Comment: This is working for this output, if I need a slightly different output how to get that? I have edited the question

Comment: Updated for new data

Answer (score 0):

As I previously suggested, I think it can be done *much* easier with a simple `split()`. The strings always follow the same pattern. All you need to do is split at whitespace and take out the second and fourth element from the resulting lists.

```py
elems = list()
for e in my_list:
    # e.g., the first element becomes
    # ['from', 'ab1c_table', 'in', 'WXY', 'previous', 'in', 'time']
    parts = e.split()
    elems.extend([parts[1], parts[3]])

print(elems)
```

**Result:**

```py
['ab1c_table',
 'WXY',
 'abc3_table',
 'MNO',
 'ab1_cow_table',
 'DZMC1_IN',
 'abc4_table',
 'ERDU']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a pattern that matches the strings and match for example either previous or current using `(?:previous|current)` , and capture the last part of the first line in group 1.

First check if there is a match, and if there is set the new value to the group 1 value.

If there is no match, leave the value unmodified.

```
\bfrom \w+ in (\w+)\nprevious in time\b
```

See the capture group value in green in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CO0GgA/1).

```
import re

pattern = r"\bfrom \w+ in (\w+)\n(?:previous|current) in time\b"
my_list = ['from ab1c_table in WXY\nprevious in time', 'from abc3_table in MNO\nprevious in time']

for n, i in enumerate(my_list):
    m = re.match(pattern, i)
    if m:
        my_list[n] = m.group(1)

print(my_list)
```

Output

```
['WXY', 'MNO']
```